# Как избавиться от ошибки object inject is not a member of package com.google

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework

У меня есть сервер на Scala.
Он запускается но появляется ошибка в контроллере

object inject is not a member of package com.google

controller/aplication

```
package controllers

import java.nio.ByteBuffer
import boopickle.Default._
import com.google.inject.Inject
import play.api.{Configuration, Environment}
import play.api.mvc._
import services.ApiService
import spatutorial.shared.Api 

...

class Application @Inject() (implicit val config: Configuration, env: Environment) extends Controller {
  val apiService = new ApiService()

...
```

Как можно исправить эту ошибку ?

Дополнения:

Так в файле settings.scala у меня добавляются зависимости.

```
  val jvmDependencies = Def.setting(Seq(
    "com.vmunier" %% "scalajs-scripts" % versions.scalajsScripts,
    "org.webjars" % "font-awesome" % "4.3.0-1" % Provided,
    "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % versions.bootstrap % Provided,
    "com.lihaoyi" %% "utest" % versions.uTest % Test
  ))
```

Как мне правильно вставить зависимость для guice ?
Он другой вид имеет.
"libraryDependencies += guice"

После:
В связи с обновлнием фреймворка. появилась такая ошибка.

```
[RuntimeException: 
The global application reference is disabled. Play's global state is deprecated and will
be removed in a future release. You should use dependency injection instead. To enable
the global application anyway, set play.allowGlobalApplication = true.
       ]
```

Из документации:

play.allowGlobalApplication defaults to false
play.allowGlobalApplication = false is set by default in Play 2.7.0. This means Play.current will throw an exception when called. You can set this to true to make Play.current and other deprecated static helpers work again, but be aware that this feature will be removed in future versions.

In the future, if you still need to use static instances of application components, you can use static injection to inject them using Guice, or manually set static fields on startup in your application loader. These approaches should be forward compatible with future versions of Play, as long as you are careful never to run apps concurrently (e.g., in tests).

Since Play.current is still called by some deprecated APIs, when using such APIs, you need to add the following line to your application.conf file:

play.allowGlobalApplication = true

Comment: Попробуй `import javax.inject.Inject` вместо `import com.google.inject.Inject`.

Comment: Сейчас другая ошибка.
RuntimeException: No application loader is configured. Please configure an application loader either using the play.application.loader configuration property, or by depending on a module that configures one. You can add the Guice support module by adding "libraryDependencies += guice" to your build.sbt.

Я прадв найти только не могу этот плагин...
scala-guice есть репозиторий но с ним не работает...Может быть я не правильно зависимость добавил...Завтра посмотрю.
https://github.com/codingwell/scala-guice

Comment: scala-guice не обязателен (но с ним удобно). Тебе скорей всего достаточно добавить переменную `guice`, к `libraryDependencies` как в сообщении об ошибке. Эта переменная `guice` идёт в составе play-framework, но добавлять зависимость `guice` к твоему проекту тебе надо вручную. Вообще, сам Play-framework - добавляется в твой проект в виде sbt плагина, поэтому перезапускай sbt если ты только-только добавил play-framework.

Comment: А как мне саму зависимость добавить ? Она другой вид имееет нежели другие зависимости ? (В дополнениях к вопросу я указал как подключаются файлы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) В [документации](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Declaring-runtime-DI-dependencies) используется

```
import javax.inject.Inject
```

вместо

```
import com.google.inject.Inject
```

2) Зависимость `guice` можно добавить руками обычным способом:

```
val jvmDependencies = Def.setting(Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-guice" % "2.7.2"
))
```

Но я бы рекомендовал использовать переменную `guice` предоставленную Play-framework:

```
import play.sbt.PlayImport.guice

val jvmDependencies = Def.setting(Seq(
  guice
))
```

В файле `build.sbt` тот импорт прописывать не надо, туда переменные от sbt и sbt плагинов импортируются незаметно. В других файлах, например в `setting.scala` - нужен обычный явный импорт.

---

Если посмотришь где у тебя в проекте используется `jvmDependencies` (в `build.sbt` обычно), то скорей всего увидишь что-то типо такого:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Settings.jvmDependencies.value
```

Т.е. кто-то для удобства создал свою переменную с зависимостями только для JVM. Но потом они всё равно добавляются к `libraryDepencencies` от **sbt**.

Comment: Спасибо этот ответ  дал нужные ответы.
У меня ещё один вопрос. Когда я всё сделал. У меня появилась ошибка, в которой говориться что нужно установить глобально
play.allowGlobalApplication = true. 
(В примечаниях к посту написал ошибку)
Как мне установить эту зависимость ? 
(я два дня только учу Scala) Я не понимаю пока где искать ответы на такие вопросы.

Comment: @Sergey, вообще это прописывается в `conf/application.conf`. Но я бы тебе советовал не прописывать это, а избавиться от всех использований `Play.current` в твоём проекте.

Comment: Я прочитал, что в application.conf прописывается.  Но у меня его нет в этом проекте. завтра читать буду как от Play.current избавиться. Я сегодня уже прочитал, статические данные какие то, которые передаются в проект. Но что бы мне их заменить, мне нужно хорошее представление проекта,а что бы оно появилось нужен рабочий проект.А  application.conf это файл который кладётся в определённом месте и подключается в build.sbt ?

Comment: `application.conf` хранится в папке `conf`. Дополнительно в build.sbt подключать вроде ничего не надо. https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/play_scala_helloworld_projectstructure.jpg